# CollapsingToolbarLayout: unexpected view stack behavior

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-framelayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

It appears that children of the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` (a custom `FrameLayout`) do not adhere to the expected stack behavior of `FrameLayout`s. I expect the views to be drawn on top of each other in the order they are provided in the XML layout.

In the example below, when collapsing the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, the "layout_button_bar" `LinearLayout` scrolls underneath the "button_follow" and "button_like" buttons. Provided that the `LinearLayout` is defined after the above mentioned buttons, I expect the `LinearLayout` to scroll over the two buttons, obscuring them, rather than below them. Is anyone familiar with a workaround?

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/collapsible_app_bar_height"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="@color/background_content_frame"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/some_image"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_header_gradient"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/scrim_top_bottom_banner"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/collapsible_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="104dp"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_follow"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/text_button_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/bottom_landing_button_margin"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/slide_handle_height"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/spacing_xsmall"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/selector_follow"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:textColor="@color/vertigo_alabaster_white"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_like"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/text_button_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/bottom_landing_button_margin"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/slide_handle_height"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/spacing_xsmall"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/selector_like"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:textColor="@color/vertigo_alabaster_white"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_button_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/button_bar_height"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@color/slide_handle">

                <!-- 3 Buttons -->

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Library: com.android.support:design 23.0.1 | Theme: Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar

**Pre-collapse**:

[image: Before collapsing]

**Mid-collapse**:

[image: Mid-collapsing]

Comment: Could you put the entire layout without hidden dependencies like `style="@style/Button.TextCount"`? Just to copy-paste and run. It will be easier to help you.

Comment: @MarioVelasco Sure thing! My post has been updated to embed the style attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap the like `Button` and the follow `Button` inside a `Layout`. For example a `LinearLayout`:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_follow"
                ...
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_like"
                ...
                />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why it is necessary to wrap the buttons in a {{ViewGroup}] in order to enforce the parent {{FrameLayout}}'s view stack behavior, but that did the trick. Thanks, @MarioVelasco.